# numpy: difference between NaN and masked array

Tags: python, numpy, nan

In numpy there are two ways to mark missing values: I can either use a `NaN` or a `masked array`. I understand that using NaNs is (potentially) faster while masked array offers more functionality (which?).

I guess my question is if/ when should I use one over the other?
What is the use case of `np.NaN` in a `regular array vs. a masked array`?

I am sure the answer must be out there but I could not find it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference resides in the data held by the two structures.

Using a [regular array with `np.nan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html), there is no data behind invalid values.

Using a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), you can initialize a full array, and then apply a mask over it so that certain values appear invalid. The `numpy.ma` module provides methods so that you don't have to deal with `np.nan` behavior (for example, `np.nan == np.nan` is always `False`, etc.)

If you have an array where you'll never need values placed in invalid cells, use the former. You can always replicate complex operations using `np.nan` and some indexing techniques, but that's what masked arrays are for.

Comment: To give a concrete example: when using a normal ndarray with NaNs, calling myarray.mean() will give you NaN when the array contains at least one NaN element. When the same values are invalidated via setting their corresponding mask values to True, myarray.mean() will do what you want, omitting the NaNs from the calculation:
     myarray = numpy.ma.array([1,2,numpy.nan],mask=numpy.zeros((3,))
myarray.mean() gives you 1.5. Without using masked array, myarray.mean() = numpy.nan

Comment: @Dr.HillierDániel However for that case or for similar others you can use np.nanmean() or equivalent

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand NaN represents anything that is not a number, while a masked array marks missing values OR values that are numbers but are not valid for your data set.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that strange np.nan behaviours, mentioned by jrmyp, include unexpected results for example when using functions of the statsmodels (e.g. ttest) or numpy module (e.g. average). From experience, most those functions have workarounds for NaNs, but it has the potential of driving you mad for a while. This seems like a reason to mask arrays whenever possible.